# Display sum of two different columns in pie chart

Tags: looker-studio

My Google data studio data source returns a list of users. Each row has the user name, id, and two metrics. For example, the table might look like this:

```
​id name count1 count2
1  Joe  16     12
2  Bob  4      18
```

​I want to display the sum of count1 as one piece of a pie chart and the sum of count2 as the other piece. For example, the total of the count1 column is 20 and the sum of count2 is 30, so the pie chart would show 40% for count 1 and 60% for count2 since the total is 50. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible currently.

You could use a 100% stacked bar / column chart with a false dimension (one you create which is the same for all rows so it doesn't split your data) or use a pivot table to show the data.

Otherwise you'll need to restructure your data so its like the below

| id | name | countType | count |

| 1  | Joe  | 1         | 16 |

| 1  | Joe  | 2         | 12 |